# Remove line on custom tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, line, customization, uitabbar

I made a custom tab bar with one of them extending beyond the bar. There is a line overlapping the center tab bar. Is there anyway I can get rid or this or hide it?

[image]

To do it, I just set tab bar images:

```
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];


tabBarItem1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
tabBarItem3.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);

[tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scheduleTabBarImageSel.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scheduleTabBarImage.png"]];
   [tabBarItem3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favoritesTabBarImageSel.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favoritesTabBarImage.png"]];
[tabBarItem2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchTabBarImageSel.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchTabBarImage.png"]];
```

Any idea how to hide the line? Thanks

Comment: Are you doing these configuration in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Its in app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: try these in the ViewDidLoad of the TabbarViewController or in the ViewWillAppear. I remember i faced this problem and solved by this

Comment: how would you put it `UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;` in a tabbarviewcontroller when it doesn't have self.window.rootviewcontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work for me:

```
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Answer (score 6):

If I'm understanding your correctly, the problem is with the 1-2ish pixel shadow sitting on top of the tab bar. If this is the case, you can remove the shadow the same way you would with a navigation bar. Simply enable clips to bounds.

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: It removes the line, but my green tab bar that goes above the tab bar is cut off then... Any fix?